# Missing one bit when converting String to binary

Tags: ios, swift, string, binary

I was trying to implement the function which takes String and returns string which consists of bits. I'm iterating through the utf8 representation of String and using `reduce` to append next letters.
The problem is that Swift didn't add leading bits so I had to add them manually. When converting strings like "abcd", "fgh" etc it works fine but for example "abc d" produces string which is missing one bit.

My implementation:

```
extension String {
    func toBinary() -> String {

        return self.utf8.reduce("", { (result, ui) -> String in
            result + "0" + String(utf, radix: 2)
        })
    }
}
```

and "abc d".toBinary() returns:

`011000010110001001100011010000001100100` when the proper representation is:

`0110000101100010011000110010000001100100`

When I'm converting binary back to String it works fine for strings without space but in this case it returns different string, for example: "abc@"

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `String(utf, radix: 2)` returns a binary without any leading zeros. Your code assume this string will always be 7 characters but that's an invalid assumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @rmaddy noted in the comments, your code assumes `String(utf, radix: 2)` is returning a 7 character result.  In reality, it could return a string from 1 to 8 characters.

One way to fix that would be to turn that string into an `Int` and then format that `Int` with leading zeros:

```
extension String {
    func toBinary() -> String {

        return self.utf8.reduce("", { (result, utf) -> String in
            result + String(format: "%08d", Int(String(utf, radix: 2))!)
        })
    }
}
```

Test:

```
print(" ".toBinary())
```

> > ```
> > 00100000
> > ```

---

Other conversions of `UInt8` to an 8-character binary `String`:

1. `String(("0000000" + String(utf, radix: 2)).suffix(8))`
2. `String(String(256 + Int(utf), radix: 2).dropFirst())`